# Loop vs branching effeciency

Tags: c, performance

Which is more efficient --

```
foo->bar |= x;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{  
    if (foo->bar & SOMETHING)
        doOnething(i);
    else if (foo->bar & SOMETHINGELSE)
        doSecondthing(i);
    else
        doAnotherThing(i);
}
```

OR

```
foo->bar |= x;
if (foo->bar & SOMETHING) {
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        doOneThing(i);
    }
}
else if (foo->bar & SOMETHINGELSE) {
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        doSecondThing(i);
    }
}
else {
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        doAnotherThing(i);
    }
}
```

I know there is an overhead cost associated with declaring loops but effectively it is being executed only once in both cases. Even though the work is the same during run time, there is more to do during compile time? Do we also have take into account where the pointer is being dereferenced?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried measuring it in your context?

Comment: No, I have no context. This is just a generic question.

Comment: These code fragments are not the same. In the first case you perform `foo->bar |= x;` on every iteration. In the second one you don't.

Comment: A good compiler can [convert the first into the second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching).

Comment: `else (foo->bar & SOMETHINGELSE) doSecondthing(i);` do you mean `else if`?

Comment: @FreeNickname: Assuming `foo->bar` and `x` are not touched by the loop itself, the code blocks are equivalent since `|=` is an idempotent operation.

Comment: I've just figured out that `foo->bar |= x;` on every iteration doesn't really affect the result, since `x` doesn't change. So we can safely write it outside the loop (before the loop) in the first case too. @Kevin, yes, thanks, I figured it out :)

Comment: @FreeNickName foo->bar |= x; should be outside of the loop. I've edited it.

Comment: two ways are not equivalent. it's hard to say your function calls has no side effect just by reading provided code.

Comment: in general, code one will be smaller, code two will be faster.  Which criterion is your objective, faster or smaller?  one reason the second would be faster is that the if statements only need to be executed once, rather than every time through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose the second one(for less if-else hits&misses) and put the loop inside of the function to reduce function overhead.

```
foo->bar |= x;
if (foo->bar & SOMETHING) {
        doOneThing(n); // loops inside so no excessive function overhead
}
else if (foo->bar & SOMETHINGELSE) {
        doSecondThing(n);
}
else {
        doAnotherThing(n);
}
```

Comment: It can be hard to predict the exact behavior of an optimizing compiler. Function inlining is pretty common.

Comment: Putting the loops inside the functions is definitely a better option. But if you weren't allowed to do that, would you still pick the 2nd one? And why is it better?

Comment: Puts less load on CPU's branch predictor.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming compiler optimization, there are two possible results:

- Compiler can prove that none of do**thing ever touches `foo->bar`. Then your code samples are effectively the same.
- That can't be proven, and the first example *may be* a bit slower at runtime. Due to branch prediction if-else branching may be (or may be not, it depends) almost free. So it is reading from `foo->bar` field at each iteration - are we lucky enough to still have it in cache.

As for compile time performance, it entirely depends on what exactly are do*things. After inlining, first example can introduce some tricky data dependence across loop iterations, or add extra register pressure, and force compiler to do more work than the second.

Answer (score 1):

What is SOMETHING and what is SOMETHINGELSE? Is it affected by "i" somehow?

If yes, the first code can run a different function (doOneThing, doSecondThing or doAnotherThing) to every iteration, while the second code will execute the same function to every iteration. So, both codes are not even equal.

Assuming SOMETHING and SOMETHINGELSE are not affected by the value of "i", in the first code the if-else is checked in every iteration, while the second code is checked only once, which makes your performance during run time worse in the first case. It can make a real difference if n has a high value.

Answer (score 0):

There is one potential difference between the two cases. If the compiler can not determine that `foo`, `foo->bar` and `x` are not somehow visible (through pointers) inside the called functions, it may have to reload and check the values every time through the loop in the first case.

One downside of your second case is that as you make changes to code, you may accidentally end up with slightly different loop controls.

Sometimes, it is beneficial to combine the two approaches by using a function pointer:

```
void (*fp)(int);

foo->bar |= x;

if (foo->bar & SOMETHING)
    fp = doOnething;
else (foo->bar & SOMETHINGELSE)
    fp = doSecondthing;
else
    fp = doAnotherThing;

for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fp(i);
}
```

Comment: That could be bad for inlining though